# postgresql limit query is very slow if result is less than the limit

Tags: postgresql

I have a big table in PostgreSQL(version 13.x) with around 25 million records. I have a limit query like below:

```
select sd.id, sd.time
from sensor_data sd 
join sensor_instance si on si.id = sd.sensor_instance_id
join agent ag on ag.id = si.agent_id
where ag.id=373 and sd.id < 24138131
order by sd.id desc 
limit 100
```

This query is pretty fast as long as I have more than 100 records. Once the result is less than 100 records (if there are only 5 records with id less than 24138131) , then this query becomes extremely slow. So the reason: result records count is less than limit 100 rows.

How can I optimize the query to return the remaining rows, if there are less than 100 records as result?

Here is the execution plan.

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=188.18..244.09 rows=7 width=151) (actual time=31.263..127512.031 rows=6 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=72910797 read=294836
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=188.18..9250116.49 rows=1158024 width=151) (actual time=31.262..127512.026 rows=6 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=72910797 read=294836
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=188.03..8967959.28 rows=1158024 width=137) (actual time=31.252..127512.008 rows=6 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=72910785 read=294836
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=185.52..8953479.70 rows=1158024 width=120) (actual time=31.142..127511.881 rows=6 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=72910780 read=294836
                    ->  Merge Append  (cost=185.24..1915327.43 rows=23656775 width=91) (actual time=31.122..93377.738 rows=23654729 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: sd_1.id DESC
                          Buffers: shared hit=1946636 read=294793
                          ->  Index Scan Backward using "100_226_sensor_data_pkey" on _hyper_9_100_chunk sd_1  (cost=0.29..621.01 rows=20164 width=546) (actual time=9.677..111.407 rows=20184 loops=1)
----REMOVED MIDDLE SECTION-----
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=2638 read=6
Planning Time: 169.541 ms
Execution Time: 127514.964 ms
```

Sorry, I can't copy all the plan info in the middle section because it is very long and I exceed the character limit allowed here.
What I don't understand is why it reads so many rows? The output has only 6 rows. If I use Limit 5, then it will always count 5 rows and the response is very fast. As long as the record count is below LIMIT count, the response is very quick. I have an index on sensor_data.sensor_instance_id. Also for id of course.

Comment: Do you have exactly this index : *CREATE INDEX X ON sensor_data  (agent, id)* in your table ?

Comment: Have you checked the request times with limit and without multiple times and took the average?
Because if not it can simply be that the DB has cached the statement and result without LIMIT and takes longer for a clean run with limit statement.

Beside that, it seems to be an execution/cache thing you're not aware of it should be fine. Nothing more to identify. As @SQLpro said you can impact performance with an proper index.

Comment: The solution is to use an index for the `WHRRE` condition rather than for `ORDER BY`. Since I know neither the table nor the index definitions, that is all I can say.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have updated the question. I have 2 indexes for sensor_data table. 1 by id desc and other for sensor_instance_id. What else I can add for indexes? The query is pretty fast if the result count is greater than the limit

Comment: You should add the `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE INDEX` statements to the question. The execution plans should be complete. It would also be interesting to see the plan for the same query without `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` (plan `EXPLAIN` might suffice).

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue for my case. The table I tried to query was a hypertable. So it was scanning in all the chunks of the time series data segments (shards). So I had to modify the query to limit the search within a given time frame. Then the search became very fast. So basically in my case, the issue was that it was a hypertable.